# How can use before_filter :autenicate for multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problems to many users with instruction before_filter: authenticate_docente in alumnos_controller.rb file, I would like to know how I can add multiple users, my interest is that the teaching, administrative and managerial users to enter the view of students.

```
class AlumnosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_docente!

  # GET /alumnos
  # GET /alumnos.json
  def index
    @alumnos = Alumno.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @alumnos }
    end
  end
```

It is declared in this way for a user, but I wonder how I do it for multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a role management framework for your rails app, such as [rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify).

Comment: I need to use devise, and not if it is possible.

Comment: devise is for authentication, they are different and not conflict. According to your description, a user has different roles(teaching, administrative and managerial) and it need a role management to handle which role can access the page.

Comment: Actually, I use devise + cancan + rolify in my rails app at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) in conjunction with [Authority](https://github.com/nathanl/authority). These both work after devise has done the authentication.

What I like about this setup is the clear separation of tasks between the two. With Rolify, roles are just named resources on an instance of a model. There is no preconception on what it means, merely a "tag". Authority allows you to create logic that queries those tags and ask questions like "readable_by?".